# How to use global $wpdb query to run SQL query and echoing the result

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to count the total events using the following SQL query. I am using global $wpdb to echo the results and to store them into a variable.

```
global $wpdb;
$current_d_t = strtotime(date("y-m-d"));
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(post.ID) as eventCountUpcoming FROM wp_posts AS post LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS meta ON post.ID = meta.post_id WHERE post.post_type =  'ajde_events' AND meta.meta_key = 'evcal_erow' AND meta.meta_value > $current_d_t  AND post.post_status =  'publish' GROUP BY post.ID";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
$result_more = $result->fetch_assoc();
$countEvent = $result_more['eventCountUpcoming'];
```

getting this error

**Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on an array**

Tried for each loop too, using the following code,

```
foreach ($result  as $result_more){
$countEvent = $result_more['eventCountUpcoming'];
}
```

but getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

`$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);` returns an array of results.

In order to echo the results, try looping the array:

```php
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_A);
foreach ($result  as $res){
   var_dump($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for one variable as the result. You can try using `$wpdb->get_var()`

```
global $wpdb;
$current_d_t = strtotime(date("y-m-d"));
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(post.ID) as eventCountUpcoming
    FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS post LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS meta
    ON post.ID = meta.post_id
    WHERE post.post_type = 'ajde_events'
      AND meta.meta_key = 'evcal_erow'
      AND meta.meta_value
        > {$current_d_t}
      AND post.post_status = 'publish';"
$result = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
```

Then `$result` should be your count.

Groupby shouldn't be necessary if you're just counting Post ID's